# Delay of methods execution in Java

Tags: java, loops, methods, awt

I have a problem with the execution of the methods in a for loop. I want my program to execute the `programmedMoving()` method 5 times.

This `programmedMoving()` method consists of two methods:

the first one ( `chooseTheDirection()` ) executes some algorithm and returns the `Point2D` towards which the object should move;

the second one ( `moveToThePoint()` ) should get this point and move the object.

```
public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent e) {
if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_H) {
            for(int i=0; i<5; i++{
               programmedMoving();
            }
        }
}

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

private void programmedMoving(){
        chooseTheDirection();  //returns the Point2D
        moveToThePoint();//according to the direction starts moving the point
    }
```

The problem is that it executes `chooseTheDirection()` method 5 times without waiting for the `moveToThePoint()` method to finish it's execution. So, by the time the object on the `JPanel` starts actually moving, the `chooseTheDirection()` method already provides 5 `Point2D` points, whereas I need it to provide only one, and wait for the end of the next method.

Could anyone tell me what am I doing wrong? Thank you.

[image]

ADDITIONALLY:

```
private Direction chooseDirection(){
    final List<Direction> directionList = Collections.unmodifiableList(Arrays.asList(Direction.values()));

    int pick = random.nextInt(directionList.size());
    dir = directionList.get(pick);
    directionsArchive.add(dir);
    System.out.println("dir " + dir + " " + directionsArchive);
    if(directionsArchive.size() == 1){
        dir = directionsArchive.get(0);
        System.out.println("equal to one taken " + dir + " size of dir " + directionsArchive.size());
        directionsArchive.add(dir);
    }
    if(directionsArchive.size() > 1){
        int last = directionsArchive.size()-1;
        System.out.println("index of last " + last);
        if(directionsArchive.get(last).equals(dir)){
            pick = random.nextInt(directionList.size());
            dir = directionList.get(pick);
            directionsArchive.add(dir);
        }
        System.out.println("more than one taken " + dir + " size of dir " + directionsArchive.size());
        directionsArchive.add(dir);
    }
    else{
    directionsArchive.add(dir);
    System.out.println(" size of dir " + directionsArchive.size());}
    return dir;
}


private void moveToThePoint(){
    if(dir.equals(Direction.NORTH)){
        this.robot.turnUp();
        this.robot.go();
    }
    if(dir.equals(Direction.SOUTH)){
        this.robot.turnDown();
        this.robot.go();            
    }
    if(dir.equals(Direction.EAST)){
        this.robot.turnRight();
        this.robot.go();
    }
    if(dir.equals(Direction.WEST)){
        this.robot.turnLeft();
        this.robot.go();
    }
}

// SOME EXAMPLES TO THE MOVING METHODS. I PROVIDED ONLY ONE, CAUSE THEY ARE PRETTY SIMILAR
    public void turnDown()
    {
        //System.out.println("Robot - Turn Down!");
        this.m_nXDir = 0;
        this.m_nYDir = 1;
    }

    public void go()
    {
        this.m_nStep = 1;
        //System.out.println("Robot - Go!");
    }

public void move(int d, int e)
{
    //from start to finish
    int x = d + this.m_nStep * this.m_nXDir;
    int y = e + this.m_nStep * this.m_nYDir;

    int w = getWidth();
    int h = getHeight();

    setBounds(x, y, w, h);
}
```

Comment: You call `programmedMoving()`but show the code for `program()`...

Comment: you are right, sorry. I've already corrected it.

Comment: Does `moveToThePoint` defer it's effect by posting an event message?

Comment: Could you add the code for `moveToThePoint` and `chooseTheDirection` to the question?

Comment: Hello @KlasLindbäck ! Here are the methods. I also think that maybe this is because of the Timer? I use it too. What do you think? I is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

`moveToThePoint` doesn't actually move the object, it merely sets the step size to 1. I assume the actual `move()` function is called on a timer.

Here are 2 suggestions on how to fix it:

Re-run the decision algorithm (`programmedMoving`) for every step.

or

Queue up future moves. You store a queue of future moves for the object, and each times it is scheduled to `move()` you remove the next move from the queue and execute it.